# Pattern matching on a string, conditional to an underlying data structure

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Apologies for the complex title.

I run into one of these unexpected definition features. I have a simplified example of the problem: a simple parser that uses pattern matching to check if categories and elements exist and match a category. Example:

```
testcase = <|"fruit" -> {"apple", "pear", "banana"}, 
"color" -> {"blue", "green", "red", "yellow"}|> // Dataset;

categoryExistPattern = Alternatives @@ Keys[testcase];
elementExistPattern = Alternatives @@ Flatten[Normal[Values[testcase]]];
```

Parsing this to check, if the elements were defined by the category and if so, this was confirmed in print, and ignored if not.

```
StringSplit[{"fruit(apple)", "color(green)", "fruit(orange)"}, 
PatternSequence[category : categoryExistPattern, "(", 
element : elementExistPattern, ")"] :> 
Print[element, " is a ", category]];
```

> apple is a fruit
>   green is a color

All good, unfortunately, in reality some elements appeared not unique, hence the `Pattern` was too simple and incorrect:

```
testcase = <|"fruit" -> {"apple", "pear", "banana"}, 
"color" -> {"green", "red", "yellow", "orange"}|> // Dataset;
```

update the categories:

```
categoryExistPattern = Alternatives @@ Keys[testcase];
elementExistPattern = Alternatives @@ Flatten[Normal[Values[testcase]]];


StringSplit[{"fruit(orange)"}, 
PatternSequence[category : categoryExistPattern, "(", 
element : elementExistPattern, ")"] :> 
Print[element, " is a ", category]];
```

> orange is a fruit

which is for this test case not correct (orange here is only defined as a color, not as a fruit).

I tried to construct a `Pattern` using `MemberQ` over the `Values` of the elements associated with the category, but this led to something complex. I know I am missing something simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing but just to provide a different approach that you might adapt:

```
testcase = <|"fruit" -> {"apple", "pear", "banana"}, 
   "color" -> {"green", "red", "yellow", "orange"}|>;

pat = cat : # ~~ "(" ~~ elem : Alternatives @@ #2 ~~ ")" & @@@ Normal[testcase];

StringSplit[{"color(orange)", "fruit(orange)"}, 
  Thread[pat :> Print[elem, " is a ", cat]]];
```

> orange is a color

Comment: Thank you, that is a elegant and useful pattern definition. BTW I appreciate that it is not clear, it is an extract of a more complex problem. In the stand-alone case, the extract itself does not make sence.

Answer (score 2):

Keep testcase as `Association` (it was a `Dataset`)

```
testcase = <|"fruit" -> {"apple", "pear", "banana"}, 
"color" -> {"green", "red", "yellow", "orange"}|>;
```

Have a cup of coffee, clear your brain and think of the following simple approach:

```
StringSplit[{"color(orange)", "fruit(orange)"}, 
  PatternSequence[category : categoryExistPattern, "(", element : elementExistPattern, ")"] 
    :> Print[element, " is a " , category, "?  ",MemberQ[testcase[category], element]]];
```

> orange is a color?  True
>
> orange is a fruit?  False